# Add a value to an existing Key value pair ruby hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

My ruby script filters a log and generates a hash like this

```
scores = {"Rahul" => "273", "John"=> "202", "coventry" => "194"}
```

by skipping  multiple values for a key which is obvious

log file will be like this

> Rahul has 273 Rahul has 217 John has 202 Coventry has 194

Is it Possible to generate something like this

```
scores = {"Rahul" => "273", "Rahul" =>"217",
          "John"=> "202", "coventry" => "194"}

scores = {"Rahul" => "273","217",
          "John"=> "202", "coventry" => "194"}
```

Is there a way to forcefully write into a hash even though the key is already existing in the hash

I will be grateful to any help or suggestions

Comment: It looks like you want a data structure where the hash values are arrays, e.g. `{"Rahul" => ["273","217"], "John"=> ["202"], "coventry" => ["194"]}`.

Comment: @Darshan Not necessarily arrays all I want is my script should not skip writing the value into the hash though the key already exists

Comment: _"My ruby script filters a log and generates a hash like this"_ – how? Please show your code.

Comment: @Stefan Here is the code: Scores = Hash.new;
file = 'LOG.txt';
F = File.open(file,'r');
F.each do |line|;
score = line.split('has')[1]; 
player = line.split('has')[0];
scores.store(player,score);
end.

Comment: @HameedBasha: "not necessarily array" - yes, necessarily arrays, if you want to keep all the values. If you want to keep only the last value, then you simply write it normally. No "force" needed.

Comment: @HameedBasha: "all I want is my script should not skip writing the value into the hash" - it does not skip already. No work needed. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If the key is existing in the hash then it is skipping the  writing of duplicate key and its value into hash. how can we append a value for an existing key

Comment: @HameedBasha by definition, hashes cannot contain duplicate keys. Keys in a hash are always unique.

Comment: @HameedBasha: yes, it doesn't add a duplicate key, but it overwrites the old value for that key. So, not skipping.

Comment: @HameedBasha: "how can we append a value for an existing key" - now that we established that we need arrays as values, you can no longer do `scores.store(player, score)`. Rather something like `scores[player] ||= []; scores[player].push(score)`

Comment: I was searching a way to append multiple values to the existing key.Thanks all for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store your scores, you could create a hash which has an empty array as its default value:

```
scores = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

scores['Rahul'] #=> [] <- a fresh and empty array
```

You can now extract the values from the log and add it to the respective key's value. I'm using [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a block: (using the pattern from [mudasobwa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49273850/477037))

```
log = 'Rahul has 273 Rahul has 217 John has 202 Coventry has 194'

log.scan(/(\w+) has (\d+)/) { |name, score| scores[name] << score.to_i }

scores #=> {"Rahul"=>[273, 217], "John"=>[202], "Coventry"=>[194]}
```

Although not required, I've converted each score to an integer before adding it to the array.

Answer (score 4):

```
"Rahul has 273 Rahul has 217 John has 202 Coventry has 194".
  scan(/(\w+) has (\d+)/).group_by(&:shift)
#⇒ {"Rahul"=>[["273"], ["217"]],
#   "John"=>[["202"]],
#   "Coventry"=>[["194"]]}
```

For the values flattening please check the comment by Johan Wentholt below.

Comment: `group_by(&:shift)` – the kind of code that keeps me awake at night ;-)

Comment: @Stefan :) indeed, but here it’s called on the result of `scan` which is always a temporary array, so here it’s safe.

Comment: And for removing the nested arrays you can call `.each_value(&:flatten!)`, resulting in: `{"Rahul"=>["273", "217"], "John"=>["202"], "Coventry"=>["194"]}`.

Comment: @Stefan I actually find `group_by(&:shift)` very useful when the first value is the identifier and the continuing values are data points. I use this quite a bit when aggregating data since it is better than `group_by(&:first)` followed by dropping the first value or selecting all but the first value

Comment: @engineersmnky despite the additional nesting?

Comment: @Stefan yes because I am usually aggregating rows of data and I intend to retain the row data in groups so it becomes `{identifier: [[row],[row],[row]]}`